# Force codeception to ignore a PHP file?

Tags: php, phpstorm, codeception

I have an _ide_helper.php file in the root of my project, that Codeception is picking up, ignoring [code to tell it not to](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/blob/f1e93f042d89e3a74110904f5940a364c821ddbd/resources/views/helper.php#L11), and leading to an error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class App (in _ide_helper.php)
```

Is it possible to force Codeception to not look at this file?

Comment: What is `_ide_helper.php` file and where it comes from? Can you rename it (could be just different extension instead of default `.php`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [underlying issue](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3990) ended up being the way Codeception was handling Laravel defaults